# Arduino- calling methods defined in an array of pointers to methods

Tags: arrays, function, arduino

I want to somehow call a function  with optional parameters from my Serial monitor, and then from within my Arduino program, call the passed in function.

With my research I've concluded I should be talking to the Arduino using numbers, not words, and then call my functions inside an array via the index value passed in.

Using this reference: http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/how-to-diy-128/complete-control-of-an-arduino-via-serial-3300/

How would I modify the following so that I am calling a method defined in an array of pointers to functions, via an index value passed in?

```
unsigned long serialdata;
int inbyte;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  getSerial();
}

long getSerial()
{
  serialdata = 0;
  while (inbyte != '/')
  {
    inbyte = Serial.read();  
    if (inbyte > 0 && inbyte != '/')
    { 
      serialdata = serialdata * 10 + inbyte - '0';
      Serial.println(serialdata);
    }
  }

  return serialdata;
  inbyte = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example program:

```
void (*functionPtrs[5])(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait); //the array of function pointers

void setup() {
  functionPtrs[0] = function0; //initializes the array
  functionPtrs[1] = function1;
  functionPtrs[2] = function2;
  functionPtrs[3] = function3;
  functionPtrs[4] = function4;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

void callFunction(int index, uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  (*functionPtrs[index])(c, wait); //calls the function at the index of `index` in the array
}

void function0(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}
void function1(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}
void function2(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}
void function3(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}
void function4(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}
```

To use this, first fill `function0(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}` through `function4(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {}` with your code. If you want to add more functions, just create the function (e.g. `void thisIsAFunction(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) { Serial.println("Hallo!") }`) and add `functionPtrs[5] = thisIsAFunction;`. Don't forget to change the `[5]` in the first line to the new length of the array (in this case, `[6]`)! If you want to call the third function in the array and pass it `72` and `98`, just call `callFunction(2, 72, 98)`.

Comment: thanks. But confused as to how I would integrate your example with my code.

Comment: @eco_bach There, I added a better explanation.

Comment: almost there, having a problem passing arguments. If all my functions have 2 arguments, void func(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait), then how do I modify the function pointer array declaration in my setup ?

Comment: Will this work with instance methods, or just unbound functions?

Comment: @Cerin I'm not really sure (I'm not a C++ programmer), but It sounds like it might work.